# Does a virtual whiteboard that offers real time editing exist for ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-streaming

I'd like to give a presentation to several people using skype. Now....the thing is that I want them to look at a document that I previously created and give me real time answers to my questions. Is it something possible? Is there an application like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've just [discovered](http://sathisharthars.wordpress.com/tag/collaborative-whiteboard-drawing/) [OpenMeetings](http://openmeetings.apache.org/) after some googling.

Features (list taken from its web):

- **Audio and Video Conferencing**
- Meeting recording and **Screen sharing**
- File Explorer

  With public (conference room) and private (logged user) views
- Moderating System
- **Multi-Whiteboard and Chat**

  White board with drawing, writing, Drag n' Drop, Resizing, Images
- User and room management
- Private message center
- Plan meetings with integrated calendar
- Polls and Votes
- Backup

It is a more general piece of software, but it might fulfill your needs.

PS: Or you can just use [Skype screen sharing](http://www.skype.com/en/features/screen-sharing/) if you don't need to interact remotely with the board. You need to go premium for multiuser video, so probably for screen sharing too.

Answer (score 0):

Miro works via the web so should be cross platform. Basic account is free.